# Is there a way dynamically instantiate a "custom" class in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a class framework in C++, packaged into a static library (`.lib`). In that library I have a template class `Foo`, something like this:

```
template <class T> class Foo {
    <T> data;
}
```

The framework creates objects of `Foo` with a template type that is read from a file. In theory that could look like this:

```
int
int
float
double
```

So the framework would load the text file, and based on that it would instantiate the class `Foo` four times, with template types `int`, `int`, `float`, `double`.

So far this works fine. Now to the tricky part: The client application (that uses the framework in `.lib`) can derive a custom class from `Foo`, let's call it `Bar`. Now I need to allow that custom class in the config text file, like this:

```
int
int
Bar
```

Which would mean that the framework should create two `Foo<int>` objects, and one instance of `Bar`. Is something like that possible in C++, so that the framework would dynamically instantiate a class that the client application defines?

If that is not possible, what would be the appropriate solution to this in C++?

Comment: It's a use case for a factory of some sort. The clients should supply a callback to create those instances

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a fixed set of possible types for the template parameter `T`, say `int`, `float`, and `double`.

Then you could have the following functions in your framework API:

```
registerFactory(std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>>()> f);
registerFactory(std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo<float>>()> f);
registerFactory(std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo<double>>()> f);
```

The client application can now call one or more of the `registerFactory` functions, passing a function which creates a pointer to a `Foo` object, for example

```
template<typename T> class Bar : public Foo<T> { ... };
std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>> createBar() { return std::make_unique<Bar<int>>(); }
framework.registerFactory(createBar);
```

The framework would store the `std::function` objects, e.g. in `std::vector`s (one for each template parameter type).
On some `init()` function (also part of the framework API), the framework would go through its config file and create the `Foo<>` objects as before and in addition it would go through the registered factory functions and call them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a template class, it can also be using the CRTP to accomplish something. Regardless, you present no actual answer.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how that would address my requirement. What do you mean by "then you could instantiate `B` from the file above"?

Comment: I am sorry as well, seems I did not understand your requirements in the first place.

Comment: I have made a second attempt at answering your question, I hope I am meeting your requirements now. Credits to @StoryTeller for pointing in the right direction.